# Prove that for every three ordinals $\beta \lt \gamma \Rightarrow \alpha+\beta \lt \alpha+\gamma$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

> Prove that for every three ordinals $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ we have $\beta \lt \gamma \Rightarrow \alpha+\beta \lt \alpha+\gamma$

It's obvious if all of them are finite, also if only alpha is finite then we have the left cancellation law.

Now if all of them are infinite, this is what I tried: we know that $\displaystyle\sup_{\delta<\beta}(\delta)<\sup_{\xi<\gamma}(\gamma) \Rightarrow\alpha+\sup_{\delta<\beta}(\delta) \lt \alpha+\sup_{\xi<\gamma}(\xi)$ The alphas are equal so we get: $\displaystyle\sup_{\delta<\beta}(\delta)<\sup_{\xi<\gamma}(\xi)=\beta \lt \gamma$.

Is there another way solve it without using the supermum ? Is my approach even correct ?

Comment: $\beta<\gamma$ means that there is an order isomorphism from $\beta$ to a proper initial segment of $\gamma$. Extend that isomorphism.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz How do you go about to extend it ?

Comment: If your definition of $\alpha+\beta$ is the one that I am thinking of, then it should be obvious. If not, then what is your definition?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz I don't follow, 'my' defintion is that ordinals are an equivelnce class.

Comment: Ok, I omitted the equivalence classes above and directly assumed well-ordered sets. But anyway, what is the definition of $+$? Given a well-ordered set of type $\alpha$ and one of type $\beta$, what does one of type $\alpha+\beta$ look like?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz I think it means that the order is preserved so the minimal element of alpha is the first one, then there's all the other elements of alpha, then the minimal and beta and all the others of beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick representatives from $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ ($A,B$ and $C$). Let $f\colon B\to C$ be an embedding of $B$ into a proper initial segment of $C$.

Now try to find an embedding from $A+B$ into $A+C$ whose image is an initial segment.

Finally, recall that between two well-orders there is exactly one embedding mapping one into an initial segment of the other. Now use the fact that $f$ embeds $B$ into a proper initial segment of $C$, and finish the proof.

Comment: I do not really understand the significance of the last paragraph. Wouldn't one by done after constructing the embedding in the second paragraph?

Comment: That would show $\leq$, but in order to show that $\neq$ also holds you need to argue that these are not isomorphic.

Comment: I see, you want to show that no well-ordered set is isomorphic to a proper initial segment of itself. Well, one would hope that this has already been covered when defining $<$, but you are right, one never knows.

Comment: Can I say that the embedding, say $\phi$ embeds all the elements of $A$ to itself and all the elements of $B$ to $C$ like $f$ ?

Comment: @GinKin: Yes, you can. In fact, that's the only way to do it.

Comment: Great. What did you mean in the last sentence, is there anything left to finish the proof ?

Comment: I meant that you need to argue now that $A+B$ is a proper initial segment of $A+C$ using the fact about $f$.